# getElementById vs $('#element') vs window.document.links[n]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance

I think the order in quickness is:

1. **Element array**: document.links[0] // being 0 the correct index
2. **Native JavaScript** Get By Id: document.getElementById('linkid')
3. **JQuery Selector**: $('#linkid')

Am I right?

Is there a tool or metthodologie to test performance for this kind of doubts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until/if jsperf comes back online, you can use [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/). It's what jsperf uses internally to measure performance.

If you are worried about performance, it's likely that the javascript optimisation isn't the answer, but context is key on that.

i.e. the difference between using `document.getElementById` vs `$('#')` is nothing compared to loading vs not loading jQuery in the first place.

In your examples you are right about the order of performance, however your first case `document.links[0]` is a bad way to write code, it's harder to maintain and read vs `getElementById` and isn't flexible to html/dom changes.

Comment: The page Is for a webview in an android app which is not going to change at all and is very simple so that's why i was considering document.links[0] option. THANK YOU for the benchmark.js library, i didn't know it.